# Pulling information from a dynamic table to a static stable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic table in a workbook (Research tracker - seem Image) where I am attempting to copy  information from certain columns over into a static workbook (ICCharge - see image). The precise columns I want to move over from Research tracker to IC charge are as follows...

- H to C,K to A,U to L ,AB to J and AC to K
  starting from row 14 in the ICCharge sheet.

. My code is below....

```
  Sub InfoPull()
    'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.
   Dim lr As Long 'research doc sheet
Dim lastrow As Long 'IC Charge sheet
lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

'1. Copy and paste

Workbooks("2020.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("owssvr").Select
Range("K2:K" & lr).Copy
Workbooks("file.xls").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A14").pastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks("2020.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("owssvr").Select
Range("H2:H" & lr).Copy
Workbooks("file.xls").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("C14").pastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks("2020.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("owssvr").Select
Range("U2:U" & lr).Copy
Workbooks("file.xls").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("L14").pastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Workbooks("2020.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("owssvr").Select
Range("AB2:AB" & lr).Copy
Workbooks("file.xls").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("J14").pastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks("2020.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("owssvr").Select
Range("AC2:AC" & lr).Copy
Workbooks("file.xls").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("K14").pastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    End Sub
```

Section 3 is obviously wrong, I am not sure how to amend it so i just chucked in what I am trying to achieve. Any help would be appreciated. thank you

Edit: Entered correct code, solution verified!

Comment: Please, try `wsResearchtracker.Range("K2:K" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsICcharge.Range("A14")` and so on... If `lCopyLastRow` is, let us say, 1000 and `lDestLastRow = 1500` (not necessary, anyhow), this concatenation will copy the range "K21000" to cell "A141500".

Comment: I think destination range should be `wsICcharge.Range("A" & lDestLastRow )` @FaneDuru

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns: Yes, if he wants to copy on the first empty cell.  I cannot understand too well what he is trying to do...

Comment: Where do you want copying the column? In "A14" or in first empty row of A:A column? Then, all columns in so named static sheet, have the same number of rows?

Comment: According to image, last row with data is row 13, because headers are in row 13. OP makes an offset, so actually he wants the first blank row after last row with data. So `lDestLastRow=14`. I think OP is just confused about typing the right sentence, but the code is pretty close to what he/she needs.

Comment: hi both - sorry where is the confusion? I am trying to add the information onto Row 14 on ICCharge sheet. Row 14, apologies

Comment: And didn't my above suggestion solve your problem? I thought that what you say now you wanted to say in your question. Foxfire And Burns And Burns supposed that you need to copy the range on the next empty row. His supposition was also logic, since your code calculates `lDestLastRow`...

Comment: i managed to sort it out with a help of a friend! correct code as been implemented